# Titanium - How to know if a contact person have middleName or lastName?

Tags: ios, titanium, contacts

I'm trying to know if a contact person have middleName or lastName.

I tried this:

```
var pessoas = Titanium.Contacts.getAllPeople()


for( var i = 0; i < pessoas.length; i++ ){
    var row = {
        'first' : pessoas[i].firstName,
        'num' : pessoas[i].phone,
        'id': pessoas[i].recordId
    }

    if( pessoas[i].middleName == null ){
        Ti.API.info( 'dont have middleName' )
    }


    Ti.API.info( pessoas[i].middleName )
    Ti.API.info( pessoas[i].lastName )
})
```

but on `Ti.API.info` only returns me `null` if don't have a middleName but my `IF` not show nothing... it's like it not taking this `pessoas[i].middleName == null` but on `Ti.API.info` show `null`

Someone knows anything about it?

I need to check if a contact have or not middleName and/or lastName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... in my tests to make it work I found it!

an simples `||` make it work.

```
if( pessoas[i].middleName != null || pessoas[i].middleName != undefined ){
    Ti.API.info( pessoas[i].middleName )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts) you can understand that your code for getting middle name is correct, you just need to use `pessoas[i].middleName` for it. But there is a mistake in your `if` statement. You should use escape character in your statement. `Ti.API.inof()` statement contains error. Try the code as follows:

```
if( pessoas[i].middleName == null){
    Ti.API.info( 'don\'t have middleName' )
}
```

OR

```
if( pessoas[i].middleName == null ){
    Ti.API.info( "don't have middleName")
}
```

Comment: does not matter what I put inside this `Ti.API.info()` because it don't enter in that IF even though it is empty or NULL on `Ti.API.info`

I can't get it work... if there's no middleName or lastName, I don't want to save that information.... but if there's I want to